# Custom authentication not logging in user with correct password

Tags: python, django

I have a user in my database with the login `jim@test.com` and password `jimrox`. I'm trying to log him in with this view:

```
def login(request):
    email = request.POST.get("email", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")

    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

My custom authentication looks partly like this:

```
class login(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # auth user based on email
        try:
            user = Freelancer.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

When the user attempts to `check_password()` it doesn't return the user even though the password is correct. Am I meant to create my own `check_password()` function in the model?

Here is my model also:

```
class FreelancerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Freelancer(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

If I am meant to create my own password check, how would I do that? This is with 1.8 also.

EDIT

Here is how I add my users to the database:

## views.py

```
def freelancer_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FreelancerForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            freelancer = form.save(commit=False)
            freelancer.save()
            return render(request, 'freelancestudent/index.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'freelancestudent/index.html')
    else:
        form = FreelancerForm()
        return render(request, 'freelancestudent/freelancersignup.html', {'form': form})
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

from models import Freelancer

class FreelancerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'surname', 'university', 'password')
```

Comment: The `AbstractBaseUser` class provides `check_password`, you shouldn't have to create your own. If you're following the example in the docs for [using the email as the username](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), then you shouldn't have to create a custom authentication backend.

Comment: This still returns `None` if I don't use the custom authentication backend.

Comment: 'This still returns None' isn't enough information to help us debug. Try stepping through the code e.g. with pdb, and try to work out *why* it is returning None.

Comment: Also, are you sure the password is stored correctly in the database? How did you create the user?

Comment: in `auth/backends.py` when it gets to the line `user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)` it fails to retrieve a user then ultimately returns `None`.

Comment: Here is my models and form for creating the user: http://pastebin.com/V62ZBX90

Comment: Yes, I've set it as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.models.Freelancer'` as it is in `app/models.py` under `Freelancer`.

Comment: Shouldn't the auth model be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.Freelancer'`?

Comment: You aren't hashing the password correctly in your model form. If you look at `UserCreationForm` in [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), you can see that it calls `user.set_password()`. However, you first need to make sure that `UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)` returns the user that you expect.

Comment: I've changed the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` but it's still not returning a user. When I step through it's saying my UserModel in `auth.backends` is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Shouldn't it be pointing to Freelancer?

Comment: If you've set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` correctly, I'm not sure why it would use the default `User`. Looking at the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) docs, it should definitely be `app.Freelancer`, not `app.models.Freelancer`. If the setting wasn't correct at the beginning, you might have to start with a new database and recreate your migrations (see the warning in the docs).

Comment: I deleted the database and re-ran `syncdb`. What else could be causing the issue?

Comment: It's better to use migrations rather than syncdb, but I don't think that would cause the problem. I don't have any other suggestions why `AUTH_USER_MODEL` isn't working. Hope you manage to figure it out.